# Why do Matroska files (.mkv) with '.der.' in the file name not play in Google Chrome but instead bring up a download dialog?

Tags: google-chrome, video, download, video-streaming, matroska

Usually, Matroska files (`.mkv`) that I open in Google Chrome (e.g. `https://www.example.com/example.mkv`) are played directly in the browser.

However, I noticed that files with `.der.` in the file name (e.g. `https://www.example.com/example.der.mkv`) do not play in the browser, but a download dialog appears instead. Why is this?

By the way, the download dialog that appears suggests a file name with the `.cer` file extension. Very weird.

Comment: Are you sure those aren't incomplete downloads?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes I'm sure. I experimented quite a bit and tested it with different files.

Comment: Then, perhaps, they're DRM protected and need some sort of certificate. Both `.der`and `.cer` extensions usually refer to certificates. Just a wild guess...

Comment: @ChanganAuto No, they are not. Even an empty file called `example.der.mkv` causes the appearance of the download dialog. It seems to be a Google Chrome bug.